# Installing Ubuntu server on VirtualBox - stuck on language selection screen

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, virtualbox, debian

I have VirtualBox 3.0 on top of Windows 7x64 and a copy of Ubuntu server x64 I want to install on it. It will happily boot off the image, ask me to select my installer language and then one of the options (like install sever, repair system and so on). I select "install server" and get a new "choose your language" screen and it won't accept any of my keyboard signals - nothing happens - can't select anything.

I can hit alt-f2 for example to drop into console and it works fine for me - all selections work and so on but the /sbin/debian-installer even if I run it from another console will not respond to key press.

Is there some magic that I need to know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on 4. Switched the chipset to ICH9 and enabled IO APIC and it started working...

Answer (score 1):

I did see a similar issue with a virtual on VMware workstation. I found that the some settings on the vmx file of the virtual had to be changed (by editing the vmx file).
Can you post the contents of the vmx file (its equivalent for VirtualBox).

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox 4.0.2 is available now, so you could try that. Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?